# PhoneGap + Speech Recognition SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, sdk, speech-recognition

I'm developing a multi-platform application using HTML5 and PhoneGap, and my application should include voice recognition. The Android version works perfectly, but I can't get the speech recognition work on iPhone.

I wrote a PhoneGap plugin which runs Objective-C code, and I want to use Nuance Dragon SDK for speech recognition. The problem is that I have a lot of issues :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      l792 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary", referenced from:
      l791 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      l800 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l799 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l800 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      l797 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemUpdate", referenced from:
      l800 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessGroup", referenced from:
      l800 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      l797 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrDescription", referenced from:
      l797 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrLabel", referenced from:
      l797 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l798 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l799 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l800 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l798 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l799 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from:
      l793 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      l799 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      l784 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l797 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l798 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
      l799 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also found that it was possible to use the Google Chrome API, but it needs a FLAC audio file, and it isn't supported by iOS.

Can anyone help me with either Nuance SDK or FLAC on iOS ? Any help would be useful !

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try testing on a real device and/or removing i386 from valid architectures.

Comment: I already tried, and I haven't i386 on valid architectures...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3), I found the solution to my problem. I needed to include two other frameworks to my project, *Security.framework* and *CoreFoundation.framework*.

Now, everything is OK !

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the solution was found for this particular problem, I'd like to mention that it's worth checking out [NuanceDev on Github](http://nuancedev.github.io/samples/#phonegap).

There are reference implementations of PhoneGap app's built using Nuance's NDEV Mobile SDKs for

- [iOS](http://nuancedev.github.io/samples/phonegap/ios/)
- [Android](http://nuancedev.github.io/samples/phonegap/android/)
- [WP7](http://nuancedev.github.io/samples/phonegap/wp7/)

Comment: Thanks for the information ! I will test this solution for the next update of my application :)

Comment: I checked out this iOS link and was able to get something up and running very quickly. Thanks for the lead

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this Phonegap plugin uploaded anywhere so we can use it as well in our projects?

Also is this only Android or would it work on iOS as well?

Comment: Using a native SDK with a PhoneGap application for voice recognition is (in my knowledge) not possible. The reason is that most of SDKs (Nuance, iSpeech...) work with asynchronous requests to get recognition results, so the method you call from your PhoneGap application (written in JS) will return without waiting the speech server response. You will not be able to use the recognition result (e.g to display it...).

Comment: It's possible, I created an iSpeech plugin, you can wait or even send multiple callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into alot of the same issues on this post.  I tried to use the reference phonegap project that Nuance had written but it was written for cordova 2.6 projects and not plugman compatible.  I have worked to create a really really basic cross platform plugin that allows voice recognition using nuances sdk and cordova 3.x compatibility.  I haven't really written extensive documentation on it but it does work and I have written IOS 7 and android 4.x apps that are using it.  https://github.com/chalettu/nuance-phonegap-plugin is where the repo is.  Please message me on github if anyone wants to use it and needs help installing it and using it.